# How to get week number between two months?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, week-number

I am running sql query in python, I have a requirement to dynamically generate dates and append it to my sql query.This script runs on every Monday. If the  week of Monday falls between two months then I have to restrict the date range till last of the previous month (i.e 30th or 31st). Any Ideas on how to achieve this ?

I tried to get the weeknumber and their respective dates but I couldn't find the exact function which will return me list of dates with corresponding week number

Comment: By "the week of Monday", do you mean "the seven days starting with the day the script is run"? (That is, considering weeks to always start on a Monday.) If so, how does this differ from "the range starting today and extending until the minimum of today+6 and the last day of this month"?

Comment: In case you really want the ISO weeknumber for some reason, I added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the week number between two months:

```py
import datetime

def get_weeks_between_dates(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    week_number = (end_date - start_date).days / 7
    return week_number

start_date = '2017-01-01'
end_date = '2017-02-01'
print(get_weeks_between_dates(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: With your example it returns `4.428571428571429`. I don't think that is entirely helpful.

Comment: If you want a whole number you can use the round function math.floor or math.ceil. I use math.floor by personal preference.

Comment: Hi @ShawnBragdon thanks for your code. But I need my code to be dynamic that is it has to take care of the future scenarios as well. I need to capture the weeks which has stared previous month  and got carried over to the present month. For example week 36 (I will be generating a script on 5th September which is Monday), previous week is 35 (here this week falls between two months). So my condition should be, If week 35 has two distinct month numbers in it then I will restrict the script which  I will be generating on 5th September till 31st of August.

Comment: @ShawnBragdon Is there any library which will return me the list of dates in a calendar year and their respective week number. It would be great

Comment: I don't know of such module, but you can use the calender module to get the week number of a date. ex: calendar.weekday(2018, 1, 1)

Comment: @Shawn: that's the number of the day of the week (Monday==0), not the week number. The week number ranges between 1 and 53 (for some years), counting from the first week which includes a Wednesday to the last one.

Comment: Oh, whoops haha.

Answer (score 0):

#### Find the possibly truncated week starting at a given date and not extending beyond the end of the month.

If what you mean is "the seven days starting with the day the script is run", you could use the following:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime as dt
from typing import Tuple

def one_week_from(base: None | date = None) -> Tuple[date, date]:
    '''Returns a tuple consisting of the given starting date (default today)
       and the end of the week starting at that date, or the last day of the
       month, whichever comes first. (That is, a week truncated at the end of
       the month.)
    '''
    if base is None:
        base = dt.now().date()
    if base.month < 12:
        next_first = date(base.year, base.month + 1, 1)
    else:
        next_first = date(base.year + 1, 1, 1))
    return (base, min(base + timedelta(6), next_first - timedelta(1)))
```

If necessary, you could use a function like this to find a Monday:

```py
# Same imports as above
def monday_not_later_than(base: None | date = None) -> date:
    '''Returns the last Monday no later than the given date (default: today).
       (That is, the given date if it is a Monday; otherwise the previous
       Monday.)
    '''
    if base is None:
        base = dt.now().date()
    return base - timedelta(base.weekday())
```

#### Get the ISO week number

If you have a `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` object, you can use the `isocalendar()` member function to get a tuple consisting of the year, week_number and iso_day_of_week for that date. (Use `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the current day, but watch out for time zone artefacts.)

The ISO week always starts with a Monday; it is counted in the year which contains the Wednesday of the week. The ISO weekday is from 1 to 7 (Monday == 1), unlike the `datetime.date.weekday` which ranges from 0 to 6 (Monday == 0).